# Why Doesn't a Go Function Field Setter Retain the Function?

Tags: function, go, field, accessor

Given this short program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    doer func()
}

func (f Foo) SetDoer(doer func()) {
    f.doer = doer
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{func() { fmt.Println("original") }}
    foo.doer()
    foo.SetDoer(func() { fmt.Println("replacement") })
    foo.doer()
}
```

The output is:

```
original
original
```

I had expected it to be:

```
original
replacement
```

Why isn't it? Note that the output is as expected if I set `foo.doer` directly in `main()`. Just not if I use the `SetDoer` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Go, the item on the left of the function name is the receiving type. This is the type from which a function can be called. However, receiver can be both pointers or value types. In this case, it is a value. The receiver is purely for the purpose of organization, under the covers, it is passed to the function like any other argument. You're passing by value so a copy of `foo` is passed into `SetDoer`, the value is modified, then the setter returns, the value goes out of scope and in the calling scope you're working with the original.

Try this;

```
// make the receiver a pointer
func (f *Foo) SetDoer(doer func()) {
    f.doer = doer
}
// instantiate as pointer
foo := &Foo{func() { fmt.Println("original") }}
foo.SetDoer(func() { fmt.Println("replacement") })
// now the version of doer on foo has been updated.
```

playground example; https://play.golang.org/p/ZQlvKiluu3

Comment: Ah-ha. And here I thought that value-based "objects" were do-able. Fine that they're not, they make more sense as pointers, anyway.

Comment: @theory yep. This seems to be the biggest gotcha I've seen for people learning Go. I would pretty much always avoid a value type receiver unless I want my object to be immutable.

Comment: N.B. that instantiating as a pointer is unnecessary. `foo := Foo{...}` works as well. The important part is to use a pointer receiver.

Comment: Just remember that methods that change state must receive pointers. If it doesn't change state, it's more clear to receive values.